# Re-creating bitmap image URI

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a method that is called continuously to change the source of an image on a window using WPF. It is working fine, but I am definitely not trained in this and just starting out.

```
private void UpdateLBUImage(int val)
{
    if (val == 1)
    {
        //Bitmap Creation
        var gc = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/check.png");
        var gcb = new BitmapImage(gc);
        StatusImage.Source = gcb;
    }
    else
    {
        //Bitmap Creation
        var rx = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/redx.png");
        var rxb = new BitmapImage(rx);
        StatusImage.Source = rxb;
    }
}
```

My question is, am I recreating the bitmap image over and over? Is that bad or will it cause problems in my app?

Comment: I think this question might be a better fit on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new `BitmapImage` each time your method is called. If the Uris don't change, you could define two static fields to prevent this from happening:

```
private static readonly BitmapImage gcb = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/check.png"));
private static readonly BitmapImage rxb = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/redx.png"));
private void UpdateLBUImage(int val)
{
    if (val == 1)
    {
        StatusImage.Source = gcb;
    }
    else
    {
        StatusImage.Source = rxb;
    }
}
```

Then there will only be two `BitmapImage` objects created regardless of how many times the `UpdateLBUImage` method is called.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

mm8 says truth)

But, why don't you want do smth like this:

```
   <Image>
    <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="path1"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBoolFlag}" Value="True">
                <Setter Source="path2"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: I apologize since I'm so new but I haven't gotten into binding at all. This is done in XAML right? Then, my method would what? Set a bool flag? Can I call a bool value in XAML that is set in the .cs file?

Comment: You should declare bool property in your viewmodel and in XAML bind it like in code upper. Then your method must simply trigger that flag, so the image will change.